# What does symbolic="YES" mean in InterfaceBuilder's XML?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, xib, uistoryboard

For a handful of the more complicated scenes on my storyboard, I'm trying out setting the constraints by manually editing the XML of the storyboard, rather than using Xcode, because having to keep everything in a consistent state while editing can sometimes be quite a bit more complicated than just scrapping all the constraints for a dimension and creating my own from scratch would be.

Most of the tags and attributes in the generated XML have obvious meanings. However, I can't figure out what the significance of the `symbolic` attribute is in constraints like this one (generated by Xcode):

```
<constraint firstItem="Sui-f6-rQa" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="1XK-fd-O82"
secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" symbolic="YES" type="default" 
id="PVi-ci-8HN"/>
```

The word "symbolic" doesn't appear anywhere in the [NSLayoutConstraint documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/NSLayoutConstraint/NSLayoutConstraint.html), and I've never seen it in Xcode, so I can't really guess what it means.

What does it do, and do I need to be conscious of it when modifying storyboard (or xib) XML directly?

Comment: Interesting. I can't find it in XCode 5 xibs. It could be "placeholder" or a constraint generated by IB.

Comment: @Sulthan I've only seen it in XCode 4 storyboards. It might not exist in XCode 4 xibs either, I guess - I've never used them. It might be a storyboard-only thing.

Comment: Not an answer, but a potentially relevant piece of info to people landing on this question: I went ahead and created, deleted and modified constraints in my XML without any regard to the `symbolic` attribute, and nothing broke or behaved weirdly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`symbolic="YES"` corresponds to the checkbox in InterfaceBuilder 'Standard'

[image]

I haven't played around with changing the value of the `constant` from 8 or 20 while leaving `symbolic="YES"` but I suspect it would lead to badness.

Comment: Yep, just tested and this appears to be correct. Weird; I can't see any reason for it to be called 'symbolic'.